# Understanding compatibility of PDE

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, soft-question, intuition

> **THEOREM $1$:** The equations $$f(x, y, z, p, q)=0\qquad (1)$$ and $$g(x, y, z, p, q)=0\qquad(2)$$ are compatible on a domain $D$ if
> (i) $J=\frac{\partial(f, g)}{\partial(p, q)}=\left|\begin{array}{ll}f_{p} & f_{q} \\ g_{p} & g_{q}\end{array}\right| \neq 0$ on $D .$
> (ii) $p$ and $q$ can be explicitly solved from $(1)$ and $(2)$ as $p=\phi(x, y, z)$ and $q=\psi(x, y, z)$.
> Further, the equation
> $$
> d z=\phi(x, y, z) d x+\psi(x, y, z) d y
> $$
> is integrable.
> **THEOREM $2$:** A necessary and sufficient condition for the integrability of the equation $d z=\phi(x, y, z) d x+\psi(x, y, z) d y$ is
> $$
> [f, g] \equiv \frac{\partial(f, g)}{\partial(x, p)}+\frac{\partial(f, g)}{\partial(y, q)}+p \frac{\partial(f, g)}{\partial(z, p)}+q \frac{\partial(f, g)}{\partial(z, q)}=0\qquad(3)
> $$
> In other words, the equations (1) and (2) are compatible iff (3) holds.

In my lecture note, these two theorems are mentioned without any proof. But I am wondering how the Jacobian tell me the system are compatible? And how the expression $[f, g]$ guarantee the integrability of the equation $d z=\phi(x, y, z) d x+\psi(x, y, z) d y$? The definition of compatibility they followed are,

> A system of two first-order PDEs are said to be compatible if they have a common solution

I am more interested to get the answer about their intuition (or connection) rather a complete proof (which may be beyond my scope of the syllabus).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The explanations [here](https://acikders.ankara.edu.tr/pluginfile.php/188634/mod_resource/content/0/Compatible%20systems.pdf) and [here](http://home.iitj.ac.in/~k.r.hiremath/teaching/Lecture-notes-PDEs/node9.html#eq:e1) might help. Also, it seems Sneddons 'Elements of Partial Differential Equations' has a section on it.